How to process received 'new_session_ticket' message in TLS 1.3?
I am implementing simple client using TLS 1.3 (my library).
The client and a server have sent your 'finished' each other.
So, the my client expects application data after that, but it received application data packet with inner content - handshake message, msg type = new_session_ticket(4).
My client does not use PSK.
The questions are:

What does the server want to get from the client after it's 'new_session_ticket' ?
What is the purpose of this message ?
What special action (send something to the sever) must the client do to ignore this message ? Or it may simply ignore it ?



What does the server want to get from the client after it's 'new_session_ticket' ?

The server expects nothing in return.

What is the purpose of this message ?

To provide the client with a new session ticket which can be used to resume the session later.

What special action (send something to the sever) must the client do to ignore this message ? Or it may simply ignore it ?

If the client does not want to resume the session later, then it can ignore this message.

I am implementing simple client using TLS 1.3 (my library)

If you implement your own TLS 1.3 stack please study carefully the standard first. Details about this message are included in RFC 8446 4.6.1.  New Session Ticket Message

Steffen, than you very much!
